# Website configuration to have different culture settings per subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, globalization, culture, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco site with this structure

En
 -Home
 -Page1
Es
 -Home
 -Page1
It
 -Home
 -Page1

etc

And I want when you browse to 
www.mydomain.com/en/home.aspx to have the culture and culture-ui set to en or en-GB
www.mydomain.com/it/home.aspx to have the culture set to it or it-IT 
etc

I am not sure how to set up my web config so that each subdirectory would have a different globalisation setting.

From the globalisation settings I can change the culture of the entire application but I want my culture to be set per directory.

I tried setting the hostnames and that partly works but it affects the URLs and I want the same hostname to apply to multiple cultures per subdirectory

Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: have you tried adding a web.config to each sub directory with just the culture setting?

Comment: the way umbraco works there are no physical subdirectories

Comment: you have probably found this article http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multi-lingual-sites-under-a-single-domain, but I am not sure if it quite addresses your requirements

Comment: Don't get me started on that article. It says "For the hostname use a fake sub-domain and associate it with the desired language". I did that and it immediately broke the entire website, maybe the article is old and you can no longer use fake hostnames in umbraco 7. I have no idea how to get this working

Comment: think I got it working... will elaborate later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With umbraco there is no need to add a web.config for setting the culture, and I am assuming your folders are really just virtual pages in the umbraco content section.

With Umbraco 7 you can now set a domain and a different culture for subfolders.

The "fake hostname" works fine in version 6 and lower, 
but the umbracohq solved this in version 7 so do not do this in version 7.

You can set a host name at the toplevel, 
and add a culture on each node in the Content section. 
It is one of the options of each node if you have admin rights to the content section.